# Disqus API /threads/list differs from Admin -> Analytics -- why?

Tags: disqus

Does anyone have any idea why the total number of posts calculated by summing the 'posts' fields of a query to the Disqus API differs from the number of comments shown in Analytics section of the Admin section?  Some details follow.

API query:

```
https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list
    ?api_key=xxxxx
    &access_token=yyyyy
    &forum=zzzzzz
    &limit=100
    &since=uuuuuuuu
    &order=asc
```

where 'uuuuuuu' it the utime returned by php's `strtotime('-1 month')`.  I believe I've adequately accounted for differing start and end dates in my testing.  The difference is significant enough (>25% on <300 comments) that I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: How many comments are deleted/spam/unapproved? I believe the `posts` field from API should only show the approved count.

Comment: Hmm, I don't *think* any are in those classes, but will check. Does the the API return those other-status posts in any method?